# how to connect the dictionary file?

Tags: java, file, switch-statement

I wanted to connect to the dictionary file when the user input "A"
I have made the menu, cannot connect the file through the method, where I can connect the Read() method to the switch flow but the illegal start of expression for Read() method is coming, including for the below words of that.

my full code is;

```
public class WordLink
{

   public static void main(String[] args)

   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("WordLink");
      System.out.println();

      System.out.println("A. set the difficult level");
      System.out.println("B. display the dictionary");
      System.out.println("C. insert a word to the disctionary");
      System.out.println("D. play the game");
      System.out.println("E. exit");
      System.out.println();

      System.out.print("Select a function from the menu: ");
      char choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

     void handleInput()
     {
      switch(choice)
      {
         case 'A':
            System.out.println("Option 1");
           Read();
            break;
         case 'B':
            System.out.println("Option 2");
            break;
         case 'C':
            System.out.println("Option 3");
            break;
         default:
            System.out.println("Invailid");
            break;
      }


      public static void String Read() throws IOException
      {
         File text = new File ("dictionary.txt");

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

         System.out.println("Set the difficulty level");
      }

   }

}`
```

The final output when the user enter choice A should be;(bold ones are user input)

```
WordLink

      A set the difficulty level

      B display the dictionary

      C insert a word to the dictionary

      D play the game

      E exit

Select a function from the menu: **A** 

The current difficulty level is 1.
```

Comment: i dont see any problem here. The print statement inside Read() runs which means the file is present. Use a FileReader() to read the file.

Comment: but i get illegal start of expression
      public static  void String Read() throws IOException

Comment: you cant have a method inside another thats why

Comment: Is this your problem - when you provide A as input the Read method is not executing ? Please mention where is the error that you are getting. Also please mention how you are providing A as input as I can see the options inside switch is a char datatype.

Comment: the code doesn't compile, illegal start of expression error is coming.

Comment: i posted the code which should work in your case

Comment: thanks! but same error

Comment: You are trying to define methods in your main method. That is not possible. Methods belong in a class, not in a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if file exists

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class WordLink
{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
   {

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("WordLink");
  System.out.println();

  System.out.println("A. set the difficult level");
  System.out.println("B. display the dictionary");
  System.out.println("C. insert a word to the disctionary");
  System.out.println("D. play the game");
  System.out.println("E. exit");
  System.out.println();

  System.out.print("Select a function from the menu: ");
  char choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

  switch(choice)
  {
     case 'A':
        System.out.println("Option 1");
       String content = Read();
       //use it 
        break;
     case 'B':
        System.out.println("Option 2");
        break;
     case 'C':
        System.out.println("Option 3");
        break;
     default:
        System.out.println("Invailid");
        break;
  }
}// main() closed here


  public static String Read() throws IOException//removed void 
  {

    String content = "";
     File text = new File ("dictionary.txt");

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(text));
     // your need to read file here and save into content to use it later

     System.out.println("Set the difficulty level");

     return content;//return a String
  }

   //}// removed this

}// extra character removed here
```

Comment: same error comes!
WordLink.java:54: error: illegal start of expression
      public static void String Read() throws IOException

Comment: could you please post the complete code

Comment: I edited the code

Comment: please use correct formatting for code posting. Remove old code ->Select all source code from your file -> paste all code --> select the pasted code and press `control K` to auto format.

Comment: was in a hurry so fixed the major issues with the code. now just read the file content and save it